# Polymorphic function `car' could not be applied to arguments

Tags: racket, typed-racket

I want to use typed/racket to implement the "LET" language in eopl, but I encounter problems：
I try to implement three functions( empty-env, extend-env, apply-env ), but I don't know how to label the type information, and racket cannot automatically deduce the types of these three functions.
I tried to use any, but I still encountered problems：

```
(: empty-env (-> Any))
(define empty-env
  (lambda () (list 'empty-env)))

(: extend-env (-> Any Any Any Any))
(define extend-env
  (lambda (var val env)
    (list 'extend-env var val env)))

(: apply-env (-> Any Any Any))
(define apply-env
  (lambda (env search-var)
    (cond [(eqv? (car env) 'empty-env) (None)]
          [(eqv? (car env) 'extend-env)
           (let ([saved-var (cadr env)]
                 [saved-val (caddr env)]
                 [saved-env (cadddr env)])
             (if (eqv? search-var saved-var)
                 saved-val
                 (apply-env saved-env search-var)))]
          [else (None)])))
```

The error prompted by racket is：

> Type Checker: Polymorphic function `car' could not be applied to arguments:
> Domains: (Listof a)
> (Pairof a b)
> Arguments: Any
> in: (car env)

How can I correctly label the type information

Comment: my guess is it should be `(Listof a)`, judging from the error message and your code: you call `(car env)` inside the function `(: apply-env (-> Any Any Any)) (define apply-env (lambda (env search-var) ...` which looks to me as meaning that `env` has type `Any`. but `car` says it only knows how to work with `(Listof a)` or `(Pairof a b)`. so probably it should be `(: apply-env (-> (Listof a) (Listof a) <something>))`

Comment: I tried  (Listof  Any) but . ```Type Checker: type mismatch
  expected: (Listof Any)
  given: Any in: saved-env```

Comment: Choosing `Any` as the environment type was a bad move. Type systems are most useful when you are specific, and if you use `Any` everywhere you may as well not use a type system at all.

Answer (score 3):

```
#lang typed/racket

(define-type EmptyEnv '(empty-env))
(define-type Env      (U EmptyEnv
                         (List 'extend-env Any Any Env)))

(define (None) 'None)

(: empty-env (-> Env))
(define empty-env
  (lambda () (list 'empty-env)))

(: extend-env (-> Any Any Env Env))
(define extend-env
  (lambda (var val env)
    (list 'extend-env var val env)))

(: apply-env (-> Env Any Any))
(define apply-env
  (lambda (env search-var)
    (cond [(eqv? (car env) 'empty-env) (None)]
          [(eqv? (car env) 'extend-env)
           (let ([saved-var (cadr env)]
                 [saved-val (caddr env)]
                 [saved-env (cadddr env)])
             (if (eqv? search-var saved-var)
                 saved-val
                 (apply-env saved-env search-var)))]
          [else (None)])))

(define env (extend-env 'a 42 (empty-env)))
env
(apply-env env 'a)
```

Answer (score 2):

<s>I've found that having a list of arbitrary length of mixed types doesn't really play well with typed Racket</s> (True, but not relevant to OP's original code; I was looking at an earlier version of mine when I said that), and that `Any` should be used sparingly (If you're using it for all types, might as well use normal Racket, for one). Using a list of pairs for your environment (Or better yet a list of `struct`s, but I'm not familiar with EOPL and what it covers) is the way to go here. Something like:

```lisp
#lang typed/racket

;; Type that associates a symbol with an arbitrary value                                                                                                                                                                                         
(define-type Binding (Pair Symbol Any))
;; A list of these is your environment/symbol table.                                                                                                                                                                                             
(define-type Env (Listof Binding))

(: empty-env (-> Env))
(define empty-env
  (lambda () '()))

(: extend-env (-> Symbol Any Env Env))
(define extend-env
  (lambda (var val env)
    (cons (cons var val) env)))

;; made up so the below will compile                                                                                                                                                                                                             
(define None (lambda () 'None))

(: apply-env (-> Env Symbol Any))
(define apply-env
  (lambda (env search-var)
    (if (null? env)
        (None)
        (let ([saved-var (caar env)]
              [saved-val (cdar env)])
          (if (eqv? search-var saved-var)
              saved-val
              (apply-env (cdr env) search-var))))))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but how can I mix up the normal racket and typed/racket?

Comment: @WEI_CAO You can use TR modules from normal Racket without having to do anything special. The other way requires some work; see https://docs.racket-lang.org/ts-guide/typed-untyped-interaction.html